# Suggestion of books on Integral Calculus of Several Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, book-recommendation, big-list

I'd like recommendations of books on integral calculus of several variables (double integral until Gauss's theorem) that contains challenging(hard) problems. And I'd like books in languages other than English, because those who are in that language I already know. Again, I don't want books hard in formal proofs but a book that contain interesting problems.

Comment: It's in English, but do you know [Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/vectorcalculus.html) by Hubbard and Hubbard? (In any case, it might help if you listed the books you _do_ know, and whether or not you've worked though them.)